# PHP hide or cut part of image by unwanted text or sign on the picture

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, hide

How to hide or cut or blur for example car numbers on image?

so if i have thousand of image with cars like this
[image]

and i want to get something like this

[image]

So in which direction i should work to do this thing? There are default tools for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a face detection tool. For PHP, I know this script:

https://github.com/mauricesvay/php-facedetection

(Here is the detailed usage: http://www.codediesel.com/algorithms/face-detection-in-images-using-php/)

Just for fun, take a look in Google's Algorithm for Maps License Plate Blur tool:

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/pt-BR//archive/papers/cbprivacy_iccv09.pdf

Comment: * Obviously in your case wouldn't be a "face" detection, but is a start :)